# Trim maximum prefix consisting of same elements

Tags: list, prolog

I'm having a hard time coming up with an efficient clause set for the following problem: given a list `X` find its maximum prefix consisting of same elements along with the remaining suffix. That is:

```
| ?- trim([a,a,a,b,b,c], [a,a,a], [b,b,c]).
yes

| ?- trim([a,a,a,a,b,b,c,c], X, Y).
X = [a,a,a,a],
Y = [b,b,c,c]
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
same([]).
same([_]).
same([X,X|T]) :- same([X|T]).

trim([], [], []).
trim(L, L, []) :- same(L).
trim(L, [A|B], [C|D]) :- append([A|B], [C|D], L), A \= C, same([A|B]).
```

The `append` part doesn't seem very efficient though. Is there a simple, iterative way to accomplish this?

Comment: Could you clarify the problem a bit more? For example, is this true? `trim([a,a,b,b,c], [a,a,b,b], [c])`? Or is it necessary for the second argument to have all the same element?

Comment: Since `same([])` is true, then you accept the solution, `trim([a,b,c], [], [a,b,c])`?

Comment: @lurker It should be `trim([a,a,b,b,c], [a,a], [b,b,c])` and `trim([a,b,c], [a], [b,c])` respectively. Suffix should be non-empty and have all same elements while being as long as possible. I should've probably clarified that Suffix has to be non-empty, unless the input list is empty, in which case `trim([], [], [])` holds.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. When you say, *Suffix should be non-empty and have all same elements while being as long as possible* I assume you mean prefix, not suffix.

Comment: @lurker Yeah of course, my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thinking about this problem from the start, we know we want the trivial case to be true:

```
trim([], [], []).
```

Then we want the longest repeated element prefix case:

```
trim([X], [X], []).           % Trivial case
trim([X,Y|T], [X], [Y|T]) :-  % Non-repeating element, ends recursion
    dif(X, Y).
trim([X,X|T], [X|Xs], S) :-   % Repeating element, recursive case
    trim([X|T], Xs, S).
```